# Neovim on Manjaro- No ~/.config/nvim file being created on install

Tags: neovim, linux, installing

I just installed neovim on a fresh Manjaro install and my `~/.config/nvim` directory isn't being generated. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and I still have the same issue. I also ran a search for init.vim and there was no file on my system, the only relevant file I could find was `sysinit.vim` in `/usr/share/nvim`.  My `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set to `~/.config`. Can I just create a `~/.config/nvim` directory that contains `init.vim`, or is there a directory I should copy to that location? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. Just create `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and neovim will find it. Nothing magic happens; neovim simply looks for an init.vim file at that location.

(You can check all the files installed by a package with e.g. `pacman -Ql neovim`)